# hbase master not starting

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am running HBase on Hadoop in standalone mode. I have successfully installed hadoop,zookeeper and hbase but in hbase master is not starting. Below is my hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/kumar/hdata/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I have started hadoop and zookeeper services:

```
start-all.sh
zkServer.sh start
start-hbase.sh
```

and the processes I am getting in Jps command

```
2133 DataNode
1974 NameNode
2679 NodeManager
2365 SecondaryNameNode
3917 QuorumPeerMain
2527 ResourceManager
3935 Jps
```

Hbase shell is starting succcesfully, but when i run any command in shell like 'list' I am getting below error:

```
ERROR: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/master
```

After that I try to run master with below command

```
hbase master start
```

and I am getting below error:

```
    2018-10-15 18:51:51,380 ERROR [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: ZKShutdownHandler is not registered, so ZooKeeper server won't take any action on ERROR or SHUTDOWN server state changes
2018-10-15 18:51:51,437 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2182] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:34034
2018-10-15 18:51:51,479 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2182] server.ServerCnxn: The list of known four letter word commands is : [{1936881266=srvr, 1937006964=stat, 2003003491=wchc, 1685417328=dump, 1668445044=crst, 1936880500=srst, 1701738089=envi, 1668247142=conf, 2003003507=wchs, 2003003504=wchp, 1668247155=cons, 1835955314=mntr, 1769173615=isro, 1920298859=ruok, 1735683435=gtmk, 1937010027=stmk}]
2018-10-15 18:51:51,479 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2182] server.ServerCnxn: The list of enabled four letter word commands is : [[wchs, stat, stmk, conf, ruok, mntr, srvr, envi, srst, isro, dump, gtmk, crst, cons]]
2018-10-15 18:51:51,479 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2182] server.NIOServerCnxn: Processing stat command from /127.0.0.1:34034
2018-10-15 18:51:51,485 INFO  [Thread-2] server.NIOServerCnxn: Stat command output
2018-10-15 18:51:51,491 INFO  [main] zookeeper.MiniZooKeeperCluster: Started MiniZooKeeperCluster and ran successful 'stat' on client port=2182
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
2018-10-15 18:51:51,497 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.io.IOException: Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2983)
2018-10-15 18:51:51,500 INFO  [Thread-2] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:34034 (no session established for client)
```

Also I am not getting any response for local hbase web URL

```
localhost:60010
```

Comment: Share us the content of the file `hbase-site.xml` in `HBASE_HOME/conf` path.

Comment: shared already in question

Comment: Do you use built-in HBae Zookeeper or you installed a seperate Zookeeper?

Comment: Initially i use built in and getting error, but even after installing zookeeeper I am getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding this in hbase-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
```

in my case I was working on hbase 2.2.0 in standalone

Answer (score 1):

HBase has a built-in instance of Zookeeper for just development environments and by default when you start HBase by the command `start-hbase.sh` it start the Zookeeper daemon, too. The error is because of you already start a standalone Zookeeper that uses the port `2181`. When you start HBase it tries to start it's built-in zookeeper in port `2181`, too and it got the error!

If you want to use standalone Zookeeper component, first edit the file `hbase-env.sh` and add the line: `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false` (You also can search for HBASE_MANAGES_ZK variable in the file and set it to `false`). So now when you start the HBase, it just starts HBase Daemon and not Zookeeper anymore. Remember you should start the Zookeeper daemon before HBase.

Comment: I edited the file and stopped all services and start again in below manner
start-all.sh
zkServer.sh start
start-hbase.sh

and still getting same error in hbase shell :"ERROR: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/master"
and same error when I run "hbase master.start" command

Comment: start `zkCli.sh` and check if hbase directory is created in zookeeper, try the command `ls /` in zookeeper command line.

Comment: No there is no directory with name hbase, there is only one directory i.e zookeeper. 
Localhost url for hbase is also not opening[question edited]